# how can i send binary data with php pdo_dblib?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo

```
php 5.6 \ pdo_dblib \ freetds
```

Windows SQLSRV driver has special constant for binary type:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("EXEC proc @fileData = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $fileData, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
$stmt->execute();
```

`pdo_dblib` is not working with `PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY`. I tried to use `bin2hex()` with `CONVERT` string, but it's very slow.

Also I found an [old pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2168/commits/273127e87899cac1dea0a22d4a030ea07ae6111a) with this type.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Error messages? Have you tried setting the length parameter to `null` instead of zero?

Comment: Also PDO_DBLIB is not available after PHP 5.3. Show your initialization code with DSN.

Comment: -Error messages?

Comment: Yes, what are they?

Comment: "constant not found" error message. dblib extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later, on linux it working fine. This const have only in sqlsrv driver http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Edit your question with your initialization code. It sounds like you are confused about exactly which driver you’re using.

Comment: @MaxVin did you ever get this working?